# Как сделать чтобы анимация включалась на определенной высоте

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

У меня есть анимация на JS она как и все загружается вместе с страницей, нужно сделать так что бы она включалась на определенной высоте. Спасибо заранее!!

```
const counters = document.querySelectorAll(".num");

counters.forEach((counter) => {
    counter.innerHTML = "0";

    const updateCounter = () => {
        const target = +counter.getAttribute("data-target");
        const c = +counter.innerText;

        if (c < target) {
            counter.innerText = c + 1;
            setTimeout(updateCounter, 100);

        }
        else {
            counter.innerText = target;
        }
    };
    updateCounter()
});
```

[image: Сама анимация]

Было бы круто если на чистом JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все что вам нужно - это `IntersectionObserver API`.

> Intersection Observer API позволяет веб-приложениям асинхронно следить за изменением пересечения элемента с его родителем или областью видимости документа viewport.

Простыми словами, он проверяет, виден ли элемент на экране или нет, и позволяет выполнять действия над ним.

Вот для наглядности небольшая демка:

```js
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('div'); // элементы за которыми будет следить обсервер

var options = {
  root: document, // объект, который скроллится
  rootMargin: '60px',
  threshold: 1.0 // Параметр threshold со значением 1.0 означает что функция будет вызвана при 100% пересечении объекта (за которым мы следим) с объектом root
}

var callback = function(entries, observer) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    /**
     * Если объект виден, добавляем класс с анимацией, иначе убираем
     */
    entry.isIntersecting ? entry.target.classList.add('animate') :
      entry.target.classList.remove('animate');
  });
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);

boxes.forEach((box) => observer.observe(box));
```

```css
body {
  padding: 2rem;
}

p {
  height: 120vh; /** разделил наблюдаемые элементы промежутками высотой 120% клиентского вьюпорта */
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
}

div {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background: black;
}

.animate {
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(45deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  lorem
</p>
<div></div>
<p>
  lorem
</p>
<div></div>
<p>
  lorem
</p>
```

Как работает `IntersectionObserver` можете подробнее почитать на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API);

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

На определенной высоте? Я так понимаю, имеется ввиду когда пользователь доскролит до определенного места?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: Если помог, отметь пожалуйста как решение.